Are all citizens of Saudi Arabia "considered Muslims by the state"?
According to a May 5, 2024 article in Zawia3, a somewhat polemic Egyptian political news source, 2024 source:

accurately determining the religious population composition in Saudi Arabia is challenging; all citizens are considered Muslims by the state

i.e. officially there are no citizens of other religions. (As that piece also discusses, that doesn't apply to foreigners working in the kingdom, for whom there was e.g. even a mass held in 2018.)
So, is it true that all citizens of Saudi Arabia "are considered Muslims by the state"?

I think it is fallacious to assume that a large government will have exactly one stance on a controversial religious issue like this.

@Oddthinking: thanks for the edits. I don't want to get into a polemic/discussion in comments on the nature of the Saudi government. Answers could ideally clarify that, if there are e.g. various branches [or levels] of government with different views on this.

FWTW, the Egyptian source seems to be an expat/opposition one, although that probably doesn't matter too much here except potentially for the anti-authoritarian bend.

see my answer here about the possibility of non-Muslim Saudi citizens which is closely related (but imo slightly distinct). I think it will come down to whether you consider apostates (who are legally recognised, even if only so they can be prosecuted where they are potentially subject to the death penalty) to be apostate Muslims, or non-Muslims. I suspect (but do not know) the Saudi government would claim the former. Compare the identity of "lapsed Catholic" vs atheist/agnostic. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/88942/can-christian-saudi-nationals-visit-mecca

@Tristan: yeah, but you've not provided any sources in your answer there, thus far.

@Believeitornot... source added there (although it does require some basic arithmetic from the raw numbers given). Link here https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/countries/saudi-arabia/#people-and-society

requirements for sourcing in skeptics are also quite a bit higher than in politics, which is another reason why that answer is not directly applicable here

@Tristan: despite what some think, the CIA doesn't officially run Saudi Arabia. The source of their [CIA] estimates isn't terribly clear.

@Believeitornot... sure. As I said, requirements for sourcing an answer in skeptics are quite a bit higher than in politics, which is why I haven't posted those stats as an answer here (where they are not necessarily sufficient), and have only done so in politics (where stats quoted as "official" by the CIA should be sufficient in the first instance)

@Tristan: one interesting point though at the very end of that giant CIA article is this "stateless persons: 70,000 (2022); note - thousands of biduns (stateless Arabs) are descendants of nomadic tribes who were not officially registered when national borders were established [...]". So, I suppose it's possible there may Christians etc. who are likewise stateless in Saudi Arabia, but the source doesn't specifically say that.

@Believeitornot... if they are stateless then they are by definition not Saudi citizens...

@Tristan: precisely, if there were some proof that they have a large bunch of "stateless Christians" inside their borders, it would indicate that they avoided giving them citizenship even if born in Saudi territory etc.

@Believeitornot... "avoided giving them citizenship even if born in Saudi territory", you are working from an assumption of jus soli, which is entirely unwarranted as a (narrow) majority of countries, including Saudi Arabia do not accept jus soli. People born in Saudi Territory not being Saudi citizens is not a peculiar loophole they use to deny non-Muslims in particular citizenship, but an international norm that is equally applied to the children of non-citizen Muslims

I'm surprised that so many find this surprising.

Yes.
US consulate report on Saudi Arabia

Conversion from Islam to another religion is grounds for the charge of apostasy, which is legally punishable by death, although courts have not carried out a death sentence for apostasy in recent years.


The law requires applicants for citizenship to attest to being Muslim


The law deems children born to Muslim fathers as Muslim

State department

The U.S. government estimates that between 85 and 90 percent of the country's citizens are Sunni Muslims. Shia Muslims constitute 10 to 12 percent of the .

MEC

All Saudi citizens are declared by the State to be Muslims

ARDA

While accurate religious demographics are difficult to obtain, approximately 90 percent of citizens are Sunni Muslims, who predominantly subscribe to the Government-sanctioned interpretation of Islam. In the western Hejaz region, there are sizeable communities following other Sunni interpretations.
Ten percent of citizens are Shi'a Muslim

Cultural Atlas

Religion is a core aspect of everyday life in Saudi Arabia. It plays a dominant role in the country’s governance and legal system, deeply influences culture and daily life. The official religion is Islam, with the majority of Saudi citizens being Sunni Muslims (roughly 90%), typically following the Hanbali school of Islamic jurisprudence. It is estimated a further 10% of Saudi citizens are Shi’a Muslims.

ERT

while the native population is all Muslim (85% Sunni, 15% Shia) and
ethnically Arab. There is a small minority of remaining Bedouin desert tribes.

Additionally non citizens are required to carry religious identify cards

The government requires noncitizen legal residents to carry an identity card containing a religious designation for "Muslim" or "non-Muslim."

Saudi citizens are not required to carry that card. In a nation that legally treats non-Muslims differently (it follows an interpretation of sharia law which treats non-Muslims differently). This tells us something about how Saudi Arabia views its citizens.
Saudi Arabia has expelled non-Muslims from its territory.
70 years ago the city of Najran was conquered by Saudi Arabia. After a lot of persecution, the 600 Najrani Jews were allowed 1 day to leave, or they would "never leave again".
I interpret "or never leave again" to imply that those groups who refused to leave were buried in the sand. Their memory washed away by the wind.
Saudi Arabia barely, barely tolerates Muslims from a different sect as citizens. And the clash between the majority/minority population is quite vocal despite Saudi Arabia's censorship (and beheading of journalists)... I think an official non-Muslim minority citizen population would make the news occasionally.
Foreign Policy

Saudi Arabia still forbids the construction of Shiite mosques

UAB

textbooks used in elementary and middle schools stigmatize Shia beliefs and practices and go as far as to claim that Shia Muslims are disbelievers, suggesting that Shia should not be considered Muslims

newarab

senior Wahhabi clerics - who strongly influence the royal family - endorse execution by beheading for offences that include apostasy, adultery and sorcery. They also often describe Shia Muslims as heretics.

TLDR:
In Saudi Arabia you are Muslim if your father is Muslim. In order to apply for citizenship you must be a Muslim. And leaving Islam is punishable by death. More specifically you need to be a Sunnite.
Note: I am not saying that aren't Saudi Arabian Citizens who are secretly Christian, Buddhist, Atheist, etc., ... What I am saying is that such individuals keep that belief private and are careful to show up to the mosque every Friday.

Does everyone have to apply for citizenship though (in order to become a citizen)?

This suffers from a bootstrapping problem. If there exists a population of non-Muslim Saudi citizens, they could continue to exist following those restrictions (as stated), so you would need to also prove that no such community exists. Likewise there is the edge case of the child of apostates (in which case the exact timeline may be important). For the record, I believe this answer is fundamentally correct, but it does not yet demonstrate that sufficiently (especially for this cite)

@Tristan There were some.. About 70 years ago there was a Jewish city in Saudi Arabia... But everyone there either went to Israel or died from a mysterious case of lead poisoning.

Let me put it to you this way, non-citizens in Saudi Arabia are required to carry a card that states weather they are Muslim, or non-Muslim.  Saudi citizens are not required to carry such a card... In a country that legally treats non-Muslims very different then Muslims. Why don't they require all Saudi citizens to state weather they are Muslim or not?

@Questor this is all well and good, but for this to be a good answer on this site, you will need to make those arguments in the answer itself (rather than in comments, which are temporary), and back those claims with sources

additionally, whilst there is no doubt that non-Sunni Muslims (who are overwhelmingly Shii) are persecuted, officially there is no requirement to be Sunni. Lastly, I do agree that it doesn't seem that the state doesn't recognise the existence of any non-Muslim citizens (with the possible exception of apostates awaiting execution), but that claim has not been sufficiently demonstrated by this answer

the comments about Najran and pressure to be Sunni do not seem necessary for demonstrating the claim that all citizens are deemed to be Muslim by the state (with the possible exception of apostates awaiting execution depending on how you view them), but this answer does now seem well sourced. +1

@Tristan That Shia mosques are illegal outside of a specific area in Saudi? That's basically outlawing being a Shia throughout most of Saudi.

@Tristan: agreed, more compelling than before although much of the quotes are circumstantial / inferential. BTW, one can confirm on https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A8%D8%B7%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%B7%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%A9 that the citizen ID card has no religion field.

@Questor the question asked is about all citizens being Muslim, and not all citizens being Sunni. Evidence of the persecution of Shiis & Jews is extraneous to the question at hand (I only brought up evidence for those claims when they constituted your argument as in the comments here)

@Tristan The Jewish one is an example of Saudi Arabia expelling non-muslim native populations who could have claimed citizenship... They have done this repeatedly throughout the history of the Kingdom... A thousand years ago large chunks of Saudi Arabia had Christian majorities.

I was just trying to help you source some of the claims in your answer. You had a source for the non-citizen card having such a field, but no source for the claim that the citizen card lacks one.

Whilst I don't dispute the answer, (and it's outside of my field of interest - IDK/IDC) the first two "sources" rofl given are so utterly politicized that they can't, seriously, be used on this site???

@Tristan: It's not pleasant to talk about, but Saudi Arabia is credibly accused of killing non-Muslim refugees to prevent them from seeking asylum and thus emigrating.

@Corbin that's a separate issue, as there are a great many non-citizen residents, both Muslim and non, and this question is only asking about citizens

@Questor, "Shia Muslims constitute 10 to 12 percent of the ." --> incomplete sentence.

Saudi Arabia does not ask about religion on its census. However, it (apparently) doesn't ask about ethnicity either, so it's impossible to take this omission as proof of anything other than how difficult it is to get statistics.
Searching around, I found sources that claim that all citizens must be Muslim. The ones with references cited the Basic Law. That probably refers to this (or any of the other many places in it that refer to God/Islam):

The nucleus of Saudi society is the family and its members should be brought up on the basis of the Islamic creed and its requirement of allegiance and obedience to God, to His Messenger and to those in authority; respect for and implementation of laws, and love of and pride in the homeland and its gloious history.

The creed is on the flag in Arabic: "There is no god but God and Muhammad is the Messenger of God".
Looking anywhere else, it's a lot more complicated. There are plenty of other sources that state that there is no law requiring Saudis be Muslim. Non-Muslim Saudis do exist and can practice their faith somewhat, though the government makes this hard in a number of ways. According to Arab News in 2003:

Deputy Interior Minister Prince Ahmad yesterday denied allegations by human rights organizations that the Kingdom was oppressing people of other faiths and preventing them from practicing their religious rituals.
“These allegations are totally untrue. The reality is quite the contrary. There are thousands of non-Muslims with different religious faiths in the Kingdom. We don’t interfere in their personal faiths,” Prince Ahmad told reporters after attending a function in Riyadh.
However, the minister said the Kingdom would not allow the public practice of non-Islamic rituals. “Everybody is aware of this when they come to the Kingdom. We don’t interfere in the affairs of other countries and we don’t allow anybody to do anything contrary to Islam. People are free to practice their religious faiths and beliefs at home and in private,” he added.

(The prince is a biased source, of course. See also the testimony of a Saudi church leader on the subject of arrests made for practicing Christians who were "mixing sexes".)
As for naturalization, the International Religious Freedom Report 2008 cites the Saudi Arabian Citizenship System:

Although no law specifically requires citizens to be Muslim, Article 12.4 of the Naturalization Law requires that applicants attest to their religious affiliation, and Article 14.1 requires applicants to get a certificate endorsed by their local imam. Most non-Muslims and Muslims whose beliefs do not adhere to the Government-approved interpretation of Islam must practice their religion in private and are vulnerable to discrimination, harassment, detention, and if a noncitizen, deportation.

See also Freedom of religion in Saudi Arabia.

this answer doesn't seem to properly distinguish sources discussing Saudi residents (e.g. the Crown Prince) and those discussing Saudi citizens (the others), and only the latter are the topic of this question

"we do not allow anybody to do anything contrary to Islam" very strongly implies that even private practice of other religions isn't allowed, even though it may not be actively persecuted (most likely for pragmatic reasons, it'd be simply too much work for the religious police to go door to door at every building several times a day)

Further to the comment by @Tristan, the quotation about thousands of non-Muslims in the kingdom does not support the preceding claim that non-Muslim Saudis exist, since it's entirely possible (indeed, it is certain) that Prince Ahmed was referring to non-Saudis.
